# React PropTypes with multiple level object

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a deep object (multi-level) from React Router4 - 'props.match.params.type'. I'm not sure how to do prop validation on such a deep object. I've seen .shape() but I'm not sure if this caters for depth. Any advice would be great... thx

```
const Register = (props) => {
console.dir(props)
console.log(props.match.params.type)

return (
    <>
        <RegisterMeta />
        <section className="register">
            Register
        </section>
    </>
)
}

Register.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default React.memo(Register)
```

thx

Comment: `I've seen .shape() but I'm not sure if this caters` -> it does

Comment: thx - I'll have a look :) cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use `.shape()` to define objects like this:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  objectType: PropTypes.shape({
    stringType1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    stringType2: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    nestedObjectType: PropTypes.shape({
    //... and so on ...
    }).isRequired
  }).isRequired
}
```